# Press Enter doesn't work in h:inputSecret

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the same issue as that guy: [Enter Key Press behave like Submit in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419572/enter-key-press-behave-like-submit-in-jsf) So my <kbd>Enter</kbd> button doesn't work in `h:inputSecret` too.

The answers he got are not sufficient for me. And I want to add some code for you:

```
     <h:form>
        <div class="box-login runny-bg round-corners" >
            <h6><h:outputText value="Bitte melden Sie sich an" styleClass="seperator text-center" /></h6>
            <br />
            <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name" />
            <h:inputText id="name"  value="#{loginData.name}" />
            <h:outputLabel for="pw" value="Password" />
            <h:inputSecret id="pw"  value="#{loginData.pw}" />
            <h:outputLabel for="remember" value="Remember me" />
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="remember" value="#{loginData.remember}"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="buttons left">
                <h:commandLink type="submit" action="#{loginController.login}" >
                   <h:outputText value=" Login" />
                </h:commandLink>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>

    </h:form>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<ice:inputSecret>` to do this :)